# Entitiy exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I was given a certain project (asp.net project) that was running on a VM. I copied that project to my local machine.(A db is connected to visual studio using entity framework) The sql server that i have has the follow name.

```
"BASIT-GILANI\MSSQLSERVER1"
```

and i use windows authentication to login to sql server mgmt studio.

**I am continually getting this error**

> Entitiy exception was unhandled by user code An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but
>   was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

I am also giving a piece of code from my web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IntegrationDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/IntegrationDb.csdl|res://*/IntegrationDb.ssdl|res://*/IntegrationDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
          connection string=&quot;data source=BASIT-GILANI\MSSQLSERVER1;initial catalog=ODSDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;Connection Timeout=160&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you connect to the database in say SSMS using that connection string? It does look a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sufficient privilege to access the database ?
Have you already try to connect from a different SQL client like SQL Server Management with the same credentials ?